# Multiple prompts when logging in outside of domain

Tags: arcgis-server, configurable-map-viewer

I work entirely with secured services in CMV and everything works fine when using them on a computer that is within my company’s domain.  Our IT has it setup so that you are prompted once to login to the IIS server then prompted a second time to login to AGS (not ideal/pretty but it works).

However, when I try and access the same web map on a computer outside my company’s domain I am prompted to login for every secured service that is within the operational layers of my web map.

Please let me know if anyone has info that will help me resolve the multiple prompt issue.

Comment: If that same issue happens when you try to hit the REST endpoint, then it should not be related with CMV.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out this is an IE issue. Firefox and chrome login as expected.